# Identify esolang with two alternating instruction wheels

Tags: esoteric-languages

Long time ago (probably circa  2005), I've encountered an esolang that had two separate 'instruction wheels', and two possible instructions, and a brainfuck-like array with pointer as memory. The instructions were 'rotate the given wheel' and 'execute instruction and switch wheels' - kind of what [Braincrash](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braincrash) does to brainfuck, but with more instructions. The only instruction common to both wheels was NOOP. I *think* the language was turing-complete (possibly by a trivial reduction to BF).

Does anyone here remember such a language and has any resources on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like you're remembering [Whirl](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116204525/bigzaphod.org/whirl/).

> probably circa 2005

Plausible, Whirl was created in 2004.

> two separate 'instruction wheels'

There's an Operations Ring and a Math Ring.

> a brainfuck-like array with pointer as memory

It has "An 'infinite' supply of data memory" (which is used like a BF tape). It also has a register for each ring though.

> The instructions were 'rotate the given wheel' and 'execute instruction and switch wheels

Sort of, the second instruction is a bit more complicated and is really two different instructions. `0` reverses the direction of the current ring. `00` does the same but also executes the current command and switches the rings.

> The only instruction common to both wheels was NOOP.

Sort of. Both wheels also have a Load and Store command, but they work with different registers.

> I think the language was turing-complete (possibly by a trivial reduction to BF).

Indeed. I can't find an actual reduction anywhere, but we can easily see that `<>` can be implemented with DAdd, `[]` with PAdd and If and `+-` with Add and Neg (in all cases with Load and Store thrown in for good measure).

Comment: Yes, that's definitely it. Thanks!